# How to enable propagation in a button?

Tags: javascript, html, button, event-propagation

Normally a `details` element can be clicked, to open and close it. But when I put the `details` element into a `button` element, the `details` element does not receive any events anymore. I tried to define capture eventy, but they are also not propagated to the child elements of the button.

Is there any way to receive events in descendants of button elements?

```js
function capture() {
  console.log ('capture: ', this);
}

document.getElementById("b").addEventListener('click', capture, true);
document.getElementById("d").addEventListener('click', capture, true);
```

```html
<details>
  <summary>Hello World!</summary>
  Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
  laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
  architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
</details>

<button id="b">
  <details id="d">
    <summary>Hello World!</summary>
    Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque
    laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi
    architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.
  </details>
</button>
```

Comment: The event is running for me...

Comment: Both the `button` and the inner button `details` are logged to the console - what should be happening?

Comment: Only seems to work in edge and chrome for me @GaryThomas ff and ie don't register the child click

Comment: @ceving probably because it is invalid html to have details inside a button (from [w3.org validator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea): *Error: Element details not allowed as child of element button in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)*)  so certain browsers may treat the invalid tag differently.  Looks like ie just removes those tags and leaves the text where as ff just removes the click functionality

Comment: @GaryThomas Firefox shows only the button event. I did not test it in Chrome till now.